# Wrong Created By Value

Tags: document-library

I was notified by a user [User A] that there was a file in our document library that showed it had been created by them (in the default sharepoint created by field) when they had not in fact entered it. Due to the file contents, we were able to identify the user that had created the file [User B], and they were able to confirm that they had made the file in question. User B was not using User A's machine/credentials, and other documents (as far as we can tell) are being stamped correctly.

- SharePoint 2007 Document Library
- No workflows that modify the created by data
- File "Created By" field incorrectly stamped with another users credentials
- Exclusively using IE 7 for site interactions

One of our server admins suggested a possible content database corruption, but nothing else on the farm seems to be having issues. Anyone have any thoughts on what could have happened? Is there something that we can do a check up this without wading through mounds of SharePoint logs?

Comment: Are they using the Connect to Outlook feature? Also, is the data completely new or is it older data (perhaps something that has been posted before)?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The data is relatively new. The document was recently submitted and the error was caught within a few hours. We are not using Outlook or anything else to view the site outside of IE 7 (company policy).

Comment: Is it possible, that User A had used the "open in explorer view" for this document library and pasted these documents by chance. Then this could happen.

Comment: Good question! I hadn't thought of that angle. Following up with the users though, this does not appear to be the case.